# Accessing Java application DISCO (Kolb 2008) using Ruby

Tags: java, ruby

[DISCO](http://www.linguatools.de/disco/disco_en.html) (extracting DIstributionally related words using CO-occurrences) is a Java application that allows to retrieve the semantic similarity between arbitrary words and phrases.

I am using DISCO to obtain similarity values for 2400+ word pairs.

Currently, I am able to retrieve a similarity value for an individual word pair by following the command line instructions (see link).

I need to write code so that I can input a list a word pairs and receive the similarity values as the output.

I have tried using the code below. It does not work. The output is the similarity value for only the first word pair in the list. (please note, I personally have no experience in coding using Java or Ruby. This was written quickly, by a friend over morning coffee).

```
# script for Bonnie's word pair calculating thing
file_name_in = 'word_pairs.txt'     # name of txt file with pairs

command_p1 = "java -jar disco-2.0.jar enwiki-20130403-sim-lemma-mwl-lc -s"

command_p2 = "COSINE"

File.open(file_name_in, 'r') do |file_in|
  file_in.each_line do |line|
    word1, word2 = line.split
    system("#{command_p1} #{word1} #{word2} #{command_p2}")
  end
end
```

An sample word list looks like this:

love    hate

appointment doctor

response    fast

frog    green

puppy   cute

church  religion

boat    white

tool    silver

bracelet    gold

kindness    fake

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your `word2` variables have newlines in them.

When you take a line from a file and `split` it, if there is a newline at the end then it will be included in the results.

To fix this, use `line.chomp.split`, as `chomp` will remove the newline from the string.

Comment: I get an error. 'words_to_value.rb:10:in `block in <main>': undefined method `chomp' for #<File:word_pairs.txt (closed)> (NoMethodError)
 from words_to_value.rb:9:in `open'
 from words_to_value.rb:9:in `<main>''

Comment: sorry, that was a typo in my answer, i meant `line.chomp.split`